# How do I add YouTube localizations (translations) to my C# YouTube video uploader?

Tags: c#, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am currently working on a program that can upload a video file to YouTube, and wanted to add localizations (translations) to the program.

I have copied the example .NET code given found at [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#upload_a_video) link. Uploading the video goes smoothly and I don't have any issues with the uploading itself, but I can't really seem to find out how to add localizations to the video.

This is currently the code that I have:

```
var video = new Video();
video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
video.Snippet.Title = this.Title;
video.Snippet.Description = this.Description;
video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22"; // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
video.Status = new VideoStatus();
video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "unlisted"; // or "private" or "public"
```

I have tried a few things:

```
//Example 1.
video.Localizations["de_DE"].Title = "testLocalization Title";
video.Localizations["de_DE"].Description = "testLocalization Description";

// 

//Example 2.
video.Localizations["de-DE"].Title = "testLocalization Title";
video.Localizations["de-DE"].Description = "testLocalization Description";

//

//Example 3.
VideoLocalization germanLocalization = new VideoLocalization();
germanLocalization.Title = "testLocalization title";
germanLocalization.Description = "testLocalization description";

video.Localizations.Add("de_DE", germanLocalization);

//

//Example 4.
VideoLocalization germanLocalization = new VideoLocalization();
germanLocalization.Title = "testLocalization title";
germanLocalization.Description = "testLocalization description";

video.Localizations.Add("de-DE", germanLocalization);
```

(I figured it's supposed to include an underscore and not a hyphen since that's what the [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/i18nLanguages/list#usage) say, but tried both either way just to see (hyphen and underscore is only difference between ex. 1 & 2 and ex. 3 & 4))

I noticed that there also is a `video.Snippet.Localized` but there doesn't seem to be a way to add a country code to this so I didn't looking into that any further.

Would love to hear from anyone that could help me with progressing on this project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging around a little longer I've found the solution to my problem.
I was on the right track with example 3/4. First, you want to make a `Dictionary` of some sort that contains the localization language code e.g. `"nl-nl"` and the actual `VideoLocalization` object.

```
Dictionary<string, VideoLocalization> localizationDictionary = new Dictionary<string, VideoLocalization>();
VideoLocalization dutch = new VideoLocalization();
dutch.Description = "dutch test description";
dutch.Title = "dutch test titel";
```

Then, you add the dutch VideoLocalization to the dictionary, and you set `video.Localizations` to the Dictionary you just made.

```
localizationDictionary.Add("nl-nl", dutch);
video.Localizations = localizationDictionary;
```

Finally, in the InsertRequest you add the localizations part to the `part` parameter.

```
var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status,localizations", fileStream, "video/*");
```

And then you're done! Hope this helps anyone that had the same issues I had.